# Why am I getting invalid XML as a response from EWS calls?

Tags: exchangewebservices

Just starting out with Exchange Web Services and getting a strange error right off the bat.

The Exception I get is "The response received from the service didn't contain valid XML."
The Inner Exception is "DTD is prohibited in this XML document."

So any ideas on what could cause that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong url for the web services.